# Using parenscript set-interval function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, parenscript

I've seen many examples where the `(set-interval "my-method" n)` function is used to call a function every n seconds in the browser, but I cannot get the `set-interval` function to run.

If I use:

```
(ql:quickload :parenscript)
(use-package :parenscript)
(use-package: ps-window-wd-symbols)
```

I get a lot of namespace collisions and `set-interval` is still an undefined function.

I've also tried `(ps:unobfuscate-package "ps-window-wd-symbols")` which returns NIL and does nothing.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Update: using `(apropos "set-interval")` provides:

```
(apropos "set-interval")
                     SET-INTERVAL
          SMACKJACK::SET-INTERVAL
PS-WINDOW-WD-SYMBOLS:SET-INTERVAL
```

So it's being provided in two places. Trying `(smackjack::set-interval NIL NIL)` also causes an Undefined function error.

Using `M-.` returns "No known Symbol" in my main project namespace.

Comment: If these examples are in code you can compile and run, perhaps you could use slime to find the definition of the symbol (`M-.`)and that would give you a clue as to where it is. Have you tried using `(apropos "SET-INTERVAL")`? Do I correctly understand that you are trying to find a package which exports this symbol?

Comment: Also are you sure that `(set-interval a b)` doesn't normally have `a` being a function (not a string) and `b` a number of milliseconds or perhaps I'm unclear on the api

Comment: Apropos tells me that it's provided both by Smackjack and ~ps-windows-wd-symbols~. I'm going to try and re-obfuscate ~ps-windows-wd-symbols~ and specify smackjack specifically.

Comment: I have updated the main question.

Comment: You misplaced the `:` in the second `use-package` form.  I guess it's a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to use this functions is using it inside de defmacro ps.

As showing in the doc comments in code you can find this:

> ;; These are convenience packages that export JS and browser DOM ;;
>   symbols. If you :use the packages in a package FOO and then ;;
>   obfuscate FOO, it will prevent the JS symbols from getting ;; mangled.
>
> ;; For most web development tasks, you want to import PS-JS-SYMBOLS,
>   ;; PS-WINDOW-WD-SYMBOLS (which includes DOM level 2 and the w3c Window
>   ;; working draft), and possibly the PS-DOM-NONSTANDARD-SYMBOLS.

and the set-interval function is exported by ps-window-wd-symbols package and not with parenscript package

the defmacro ps:

> "Given Parenscript forms (an implicit progn), compiles those forms to
>   a JavaScript string at macro-expansion time. Expands into a form which
>   evaluates to a string.

take a look at [the following gist](https://gist.github.com/KeenS/f3deeca6295d7454cb17):

```
    (ql:quickload :parenscript)
(ql:quickload :cl-who)
(ql:quickload :clack)
(in-package :ps)
(defvar *canvas-id* "alien-canvas")
(clack:clackup
 (lambda (env)
   (list 200
         '(:content-type "text/html")
         (list
          (who:with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output* nil :prologue t :indent t)
            (:html
             (:head
              (:script  :type "text/javascript"
               (who:fmt "~A"
                        (ps (defvar x 0)
                            (defvar y 0)
                            (defvar dx 1)
                            (defvar dy 1)
                            (defvar img (new -image))
                            (setf (@ img src) "http://www.lisperati.com/lisplogo_alien_128.png")
                            (set-interval "draw()" 5)

                            (defun draw ()
                              (let ((w 128)
                                    (h 75)
                                    (canvas ((@ document get-element-by-id) #.*canvas-id*)))
                                (if (or (not canvas) (not (@ canvas get-context)))
                                    (return false))
                                (let ((ctx ((@ canvas get-context) "2d")))
                                  ((@ ctx fill-rect) 0 0 500 500)
                                  (if (and (<= (+ x dx w) 500) (<= 0 (+ x dx)))
                                      (setf x (+ x dx))
                                      (setf dx (* dx -1)))
                                  (if (and (<= (+ y dy h) 500) (<= 0 (+ y dy)))
                                      (setf y (+ y dy))
                                      (setf dy (* dy -1)))
                                  ((@ ctx draw-image) img x y))))))))
             (:body (:canvas :id *canvas-id* :width 500 :height 500))))))))
```

Comment: Your wellcome. I hope this helped you

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `set-interval` is just a symbol and not an actual function (in Lisp). Parenscript produces Javascript code, which can then be run in a JS interpreter (e.g. a browser), but this is not an interpreter itself.

Parenscript offers a way to obfuscate symbols, but can also guarantee some symbols are not obfuscated. [The documentation](https://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/reference.html#section-namespace) says:

> Since Parenscript doesn't know anything about the DOM or other
>   JavaScript libraries, library function and property names might be
>   inadvertently obfuscated. To help prevent that, Parenscript comes with
>   the ps-dom1-symbols, ps-dom2-symbols, ps-window-wd-symbols,
>   ps-dom-nonstandard-symbols and ps-dhtml-symbols symbol packages that
>   define various DOM property and function identifiers as exported
>   symbols (in both case-sensitive and insensitive variants), which you
>   can import into your packages to help prevent symbols like pageXOffset
>   from being obfuscated. The ps-dhtml-symbols package contains the
>   broadest range of symbols and is most generally useful.
>
> If you use obfuscation and external JavaScript libraries, you can use
>   the same technique to define your own packages with symbols that will
>   not be obfuscated.

Smackjack also produces a call to `setInterval` ([pusher.lisp:189](https://github.com/aarvid/SmackJack/blob/80f2d830195212050e64cf7916cae53cef1d9a12/pusher.lisp#L189)), but it does not import the symbols from the above packages. This is not really a problem because only the symbol's name is used here, and no obfuscation is done. In other terms, both `smackjack::set-interval` and `ps-window-wd-symbols:set-interval` are mapped to the same Javascript function.